# How to see all valid URLs in Tomcat?

Tags: web-services, tomcat, jax-rs

I am developing a web application with using Maven, IntelliJ, Jersey(Jax-RS) and it works on Tomcat server. I just wondered something, can we see a list of all valid URLs? I mean is there a command or something that we can write on command screen to see that? Regards,

Comment: The list of valid URLs is potentially infinite.

Comment: @EJP I mean for a certain web application, and valid was not correct word I guess, sorry. I wanted to say all the URLs that a certain web application is using right now.

Comment: You can use [Swagger](http://petstore.swagger.io/) to document your Rest Api.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Stefan's comment above I found Swigger to document my web app. According to [here](https://swagger.io/getting-started/), Swagger is:

> What is Swagger?
>   The goal of Swagger™ is to define a standard, language-agnostic interface to REST APIs which allows both humans and computers to discover and understand the capabilities of the service without access to source code, documentation, or through network traffic inspection. When properly defined via Swagger, a consumer can understand and interact with the remote service with a minimal amount of implementation logic. Similar to what interfaces have done for lower-level programming, Swagger removes the guesswork in calling the service.

Hope it can help somebody.